# Get number first and second and third from text line

Tags: vbscript

I have the following format in my txt file:

```
1   1,30705856804525E-7 2,64163961816166E-8
1,12201845645905    1,24157281788939E-7 2,45690063849224E-8
1,25892543792725    1,18248813407718E-7 2,29960868125545E-8
1,41253757476807    1,13006606738963E-7 2,16654658657944E-8
1,58489322662354    1,0842624220686E-7  2,05472137082552E-8
1,77827942371368    1,04479198625995E-7 1,96135836461053E-8
1,99526226520538    1,01119816520168E-7 1,8839035220708E-8
2,23872113227844    9,82917924829962E-8 1,82003176973922E-8
2,51188635826111    9,59338279926669E-8 1,76765304615856E-8
2,81838297843933    9,39840489877497E-8 1,72491425587395E-8
3,16227769851685    9,23831819932275E-8 1,69019571671924E-8
3,54813385009766    9,10766573269939E-8 1,66210121221866E-8
3,98107171058655    9,00157104410937E-8 1,63944182673958E-8
4,46683597564697    8,91577514039454E-8 1,62121711611007E-8
5,01187229156494    8,8466336478632E-8  1,60659361370108E-8
5,6234130859375 8,7910699164695E-8  1,59488209305891E-8
6,30957365036011    8,74651959748007E-8 1,58551749507296E-8
7,07945775985718    8,71086527354237E-8 1,57803938805046E-8
7,94328212738037    8,68237393092386E-8 1,57207402651238E-8
8,91250896453857    8,65963372120859E-8 1,56731942979604E-8
10  8,64150138113473E-8 1,56353241465013E-8
11,2201843261719    8,62705391568852E-8 1,5605175818223E-8
```

I need to get only value for integers on left and right value so in this example I need to get:

```
1
2,64163961816166E-8

10
1,56353241465013E-8
```

This is what I've tried:

```
' Check Noise Spectral Density.txt exists
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FileExists(fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) + "\Projects\Noise Spectral Density.txt")) Then
    ' Open the file for input.
    Set NoiseSpectralDensity = fso.OpenTextFile(fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) + "\Projects\Noise Spectral Density.txt", 1)

    ' Noise Variables
    Dim Noise

    ' Read from the file and display the results.
    Do While NoiseSpectralDensity.AtEndOfStream <> True
        ' Read Line By Line
        TextLine = NoiseSpectralDensity.ReadLine

        ' Check If Number
        'If (IsNumeric(Left(TextLine, 5))) Then
            ' Get Noise

            ' Noise @ 1kHz
            Noise = Right(TextLine, InStr(Mid(TextLine, 2), InStr(TextLine, " ")-1))
            x = MsgBox("SNR: " & Split(Left(TextLine, 5), " ")(0) & " NOISE: " & Noise & "",0, "Noise Spectral Density")
        'End If
    Loop

    ' Close the file for input.
    NoiseSpectralDensity.Close
Else
    x = MsgBox("Noise Spectral Density.txt NOT Found!" & vbCrLf & "Wave->Save As Text...", 0, "Noise Spectral Density")
End If
```

But I could not get left and right numbers in VBScript using `Split(TextLine, " ")(0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data seems to be tab-separated, so you could do something like this:

```
arr = Split(TextLine, vbTab)
If Not (InStr(arr(0), ",") > 0) Then
    'first number doesn't have decimals
    snr   = arr(0)
    noise = arr(2)
End If
```

Comment: I'd set `noise = arr(UBound(arr))` just in case there are more than three numbers in a line.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed We don't know enough about the data export to make that assumption. If there are more columns they may well contain additional data while the data the OP wants to extract remains in the 3rd column.

Comment: Yep, I didn't read the title carefully. However, it seems that this is what the OP actually wants, according to _"I need to get only value for integers on left and right value"_. Still, yours is the safest considering the title :)

Answer (score 1):

Though the solution provided by @AnsgarWiechers should work but in case, if it doesn't, you can make use of regular expressions(Replace the whole Do-while loop with the following):

```
Set objReg = New RegExp
objReg.Pattern = "^(\d+)(?=\s).*\s+([\d,Ee-]+)$"     'See the explanation below
Do While NoiseSpectralDensity.AtEndOfStream <> True
    'Read Line By Line
    TextLine = NoiseSpectralDensity.ReadLine

    ' Check If Number
    Set objMatches = objReg.Execute(TextLine)
    For Each objMatch In objMatches
        SNR = objMatch.submatches.item(0)
        Noise = objMatch.submatches.item(1)
        MsgBox "SNR: "&SNR&"; Noise: "&Noise
    Next
Loop
```

**[Click for Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dRP9cA/1)**

**Regex Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(\d+)` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit and captures it in Group 1
- `(?=\s)` - positive lookahead to find the position immediately preceded by a white-space. So the digits in the step 2 will be matched until a whitespace(spaces,tabs etc.) is encountered
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character except a newline
- `\s+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a whitespace
- `([\d,Ee-]+)` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit or `,` or `-` or the letter `E` or `e` and capture it in group 2
- `$` - asserts the end of the string